# How to get sidekick in AEM 6.3?

Tags: aem

I'm trying to change from touch to classic ui in AEM 6.3, unable to see sidekick in classic mode. I've done the overlaying component for page editor and admin consoles to change into classic -ui.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe as of the release of AEM 6.3 classicUI is no longer supported. It's no longer a matter of touchUI vs classicUI....it's just 'THE UI' (touch). I'd question why you would still want to author in classicUI if you are using AEM6.3. So much has changed that I would expect you are opening a whole can of worms full of classic problems.

Comment: That's not correct. AEM 6.3 fully supports existing classic UI applications. See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/author/author-environment/select-ui.html. See future release announcements which clearly say that classic UI will be deprecated in 2018 https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/release-notes/deprecated-removed-features.html#Pre-announcement for Next Release

Comment: Just to confirm, have you followed all the steps listed at: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/author/author-environment/select-ui.html?

Comment: I have the same question. The documentation suggests that Classic UI wasn't removed or intentionally broken, but visiting http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/we-retail/language-masters/en.html has no Sidekick. The console is full of JavaScript errors.... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined
    at en.html:1480
(anonymous) @ en.html:1480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekick is available in AEM 6.3 with Classic UI mode as exactly same as AEM 6.1 and AEM 6.2. Check the init.jsp is added to your page component. That might be one of the reason.

Comment: In AEM6.3 ww-retail project pages sidekick won't come in classic mode. Because page component is not having init.jsp. You can create new page component with init.jsp, and try sidekick will work with classic UI.